# React native application structure

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

```
1 Stack navigator:    
   1.1 Tabnavigator:
      1.1.1 Stack navigator:
         1.1.1.1 page one
      1.1.2 Stack navigator:
         1.1.2.1 page two
      1.1.3 Stack navigator:
         1.1.3.1 page three    
   1.2 page 4
```

This is the structure i decided to implement.
I have a few issues that i have not solved yet.
I want the root stack navigator header to display the logo and back button in case, and also to control the entire application state.
when i set up a custom header i have no idea how to tell the back button to be hidden or displayed. I set the custom header from navigationOptions of the root stack navigator.

Any helps please?

Comment: it's hard to help without you sharing any code...

Comment: Lets assume i am starting everything from scratch. How would you implement that?

Comment: I'd start writing the structure you outlined and ask a specific question on SO once you arrive at a problem, and I'd attach an expo snack that demonstrates what you have tried and what the problem is :)

Comment: Thanks buddy i am waiting for your solution, ill ask questions regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define navigationOptions on each screen (component) as you want, this way is more flexible for what you want to do. Here is an example for you, please note where I redefine `headerLeft` for `EventInfo` screen, you can hide or show `headerLeft` whatever you want:

```
    ...
        class EventInfo extends PureComponent {

          // Set the navigation options for `react-navigation`
          static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
            return {
              headerRight: <Icon style={{marginRight:10,color:'white'}} name="menu" size={32} onPress={() => {navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}}/>,
              headerTitle: <Text style={{flex:1,textAlign:'center',fontSize:18,color:'white',fontWeight:'bold'}}>{I18N.t('events.infoEventTitle')}</Text>,
              headerLeft: <Icon2 style={{color:'white', marginLeft:10, width:40}} name="ios-arrow-back" size={32} onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Events')}}/>,
            }
          };
    ...
```

Comment: This approach is not working. Because we are talking about nested navigation the root stack doesnt know about the inner stack navigation change so it doesnt know when to show the back button and thats the point.
The navigationOptions will be working in my example only in settings and in any of the tabs within the tab navigator. What should i do in nested stack navigator?

Comment: @user7326641 Could you just import `Navigator` and use `Navigation.mergeOptions({...})`?